# D3 choropleth map not filling appropriately

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 map that should be filling US counties by how they fall within a range. I'm not having D3 determine that range for me, the data is such that 0, .5,1, and 10 work as quantiles.

The problem I'm having is that counties are not being filled with the appropriate color by where they are on the range. I know this because I can see the values via a tooltip. It's almost as if there's another value that is being cut into quantiles.

There is a complication in that I have a dropdown to select an additional variable to fill the map with (the same quantiles are fine for these variables)

Below is where I think my problem is, the initial code, the updateMap function or within the legend itself. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
var width = 800,
    height = 500;
var statById = d3.map();
var quantile = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain([0,.5,1,10])
        .range(['white','blue','red', 'green']);

function updateMap(key){
    quantile.domain(counties.map(function(d){return d[key];}));
    countyShapes
        .transition().duration(1000).ease(d3.ease('linear'))
        .attr("fill", function(d) { 
            if (statById.get(d.id)){
                if(statById.get(d.id)[key] == 0){
                    return 'white';
                }
                else{
                    return quantile(statById.get(d.id)[key]);
                }
            }
            else{
                errorArray.push(d.id);
                return "white";
        }});
}

var legend = svg.selectAll('g.legendEntry')
    .data(quantile.range().reverse())
    .enter()
    .append('g').attr('class', 'legendEntry');

legend
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x", width - 780)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
    })
   .attr("width", 10)
   .attr("height", 10)
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("stroke-width", 1)
   .style("fill", function(quantile){return quantile;}); 
       //the data objects are the fill colors

legend
    .append('text')
    .attr("x", width - 760) //leave 5 pixel space after the <rect>
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
    })
    .attr("dy", "0.8em") //place text one line *below* the x,y point
    .text(function(d,i) {
        var extent = quantile.invertExtent(d);
        //extent will be a two-element array, format it however you want:
        var format = d3.format("0.2f");
        return format(+extent[0]) + " - " + format(+extent[1]);
    });
```

And here is the entire script rendering the map:

```
<script>
var width = 800,
    height = 500;
var statById = d3.map();
var quantile = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain([0,.5,1,10])
        .range(['white','blue','red', 'green']);

var path = d3.geo.path();
var svg = d3.select("#map")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
    .append('svg:g')
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
    .append('svg:g');
svg.attr("transform", "scale( " + .9 + ")");
function redraw() {
  console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
      + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
d3.select("#selectPer")
        .on("change", function(){menuChange();});
d3.select("#selectType")
        .on("change", function(){menuChange();});
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
      .style("background", "rgba(250,250,250,.7)");
tooltip.append("span").attr("id", "countyName")
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "mvpfinal020715.csv")
    .defer(d3.json, "countyPop.json")
    .await(ready);
errorArray = [];
var counties;
var countyPop;
function ready(error, us, countiesJSON, countyPopJSON) {
    counties = countiesJSON;
    countyPop = countyPopJSON;
    counties.forEach(function(d){
        try{
            d.lq_11 = +d['lq_11'];
            d.lq_21 = +d['lq_21'];
            d.lq_22 = +d['lq_22'];
            d.lq_23 = +d['lq_23'];
            d.lq_42 = +d['lq_42'];
            d.lq_51 = +d['lq_51'];
            d.lq_52 = +d['lq_52'];
            d.lq_53 = +d['lq_53'];
      d.lq_55 = +d['lq_55'];
            d.lq_56 = +d['lq_56'];
            d.lq_61 = +d['lq_61'];
            d.lq_62 = +d['lq_62'];
      d.lq_71 = +d['lq_71'];
            d.lq_72 = +d['lq_72'];
            d.lq_81 = +d['lq_81'];
            d.lq_92 = +d['lq_92'];

            statById.set(+d.fips, d);
            if (isNaN('white')){
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            //remove double lines of csv
        }
    });
    quantile.domain(counties.map(function(d){return d.subPerCap;}));
    countyShapes = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "counties")
        .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        countyShapes            
            .attr("fill", "rgb(200,200,200)")
            .attr("d", path)
                    .on("mouseover", function(d){
                        d3.select(this)
                            .attr("stroke", "red")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                        tooltip
                            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
                            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 5) + "px")
                            .transition().duration(300)
                            .style("opacity", 1)
                            .style("display", "block")
                        updateDetails(statById.get(d.id));
                })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d){
                        d3.select(this)
                            .attr("stroke", "")
                            .attr("stroke-width", .2)
                        tooltip.transition().duration(700).style("opacity", 0);
            });
    svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
            .attr("class", "states")
            .attr("d", path);
    menuChange();
}
var printDetails = [
                    {'var': 'fips', 'print': 'FIPS'},
                    {'var': 'lq_21', 'print': 'Mining'},
                    {'var': 'lq_23', 'print': 'Construction'},
                    {'var': 'lq_51', 'print': 'Information'},
                    {'var': 'lq_52', 'print': 'Finance'},
                    {'var': 'No Criminal Conviction Return', 'print': 'Paperwork Returns'},
                    {'var': 'none', 'print': ''},
                    {'var': 'population', 'print': 'Population'},
                    {'var': 'Activation Date', 'print': 'Start Date'}];
function updateDetails(county){
    tooltip.selectAll("div").remove();
    tooltip.selectAll("div").data(printDetails).enter()
        .append("div")
            .append('span')
                .text(function(d){return (d.print.length > 0) ? d.print + ": " : " - ";})               
                .attr("class", "boldDetail")
            .insert('span')
                .text(function(d){
                    if (d.var != 'none'){
                        return (""+county[d.var]).indexOf('/') == -1 ? totalFormat(county[d.var]) : county[d.var];
                    }})
                .attr("class", "normalDetail");
    d3.select("#countyName").text(county.County);
}
var totalFormat = d3.format(",");
function menuChange(){
    var selectPer = document.getElementById('selectPer');
    selectPerValue = selectPer.options[selectPer.selectedIndex].value; 
    var selectType = document.getElementById('selectType');
    selectTypeValue = selectType.options[selectType.selectedIndex].value; 
    var keyName = selectTypeValue + (selectPerValue == 'PerCap' ? 'PerCap' : '');
    console.log(keyName);
    updateMap(keyName);
    console.log(d3.sum(counties, function(d){return d[selectTypeValue];}));
    var num = d3.sum(counties, function(d){return d[selectTypeValue];});
    d3.select("#magicNum")
        .text(selectPerValue == 'PerCap' ? d3.round(num*10000/313000000, 3) + " per 100,000" : totalFormat(num));
}
function updateMap(key){
    quantile.domain(counties.map(function(d){return d[key];}));
    countyShapes
        .transition().duration(1000).ease(d3.ease('linear'))
        .attr("fill", function(d) { 
            if (statById.get(d.id)){
                if(statById.get(d.id)[key] == 0){
                    return 'white';
                }
                else{
                    return quantile(statById.get(d.id)[key]);
                }
            }
            else{
                errorArray.push(d.id);
                return "white";
        }});
}




var legend = svg.selectAll('g.legendEntry')
    .data(quantile.range().reverse())
    .enter()
    .append('g').attr('class', 'legendEntry');

legend
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x", width - 780)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
    })
   .attr("width", 10)
   .attr("height", 10)
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("stroke-width", 1)
   .style("fill", function(quantile){return quantile;}); 
       //the data objects are the fill colors

legend
    .append('text')
    .attr("x", width - 760) //leave 5 pixel space after the <rect>
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
    })
    .attr("dy", "0.8em") //place text one line *below* the x,y point
    .text(function(d,i) {
        var extent = quantile.invertExtent(d);
        //extent will be a two-element array, format it however you want:
        var format = d3.format("0.2f");
        return format(+extent[0]) + " - " + format(+extent[1]);
    });


</script>
```

Comment: have you used console.log(statById.get(d.id)[key]) to be sure you are passing in the values correctly?

Comment: Can you post an example of your data, or better yet, a minimal implementation as a fiddle or snippet?